# Laptop screen broken; can't get external monitor working

Tags: display

I have a Gateway NV series laptop, and the screen is broken. I have an external monitor, but I don't know how to get it working. I'm trying the fn-f4 thing, but nothing happens during bootup or after I log in (at least, I think I'm logging in -- hard to know for sure).

I've also tried hooking up a USB keyboard and mouse and closing the laptop. Nothing happens.

I've looked around for a while, but all the advice I can find involves right-clicking into Properties or other things that, you know, require a screen.

The laptop makes turning-on noises when I turn it on, and I can detect it with other computers when I connect with an ethernet cable, so I'm pretty sure the computer itself is working just fine.

I feel like I must be missing something simple, like maybe I have to press fn-f4 and then enter. I just have no idea because I have no visual at any point.

Its model number is MS2273 (probably NV58—could be NV54), if that helps at all.

**Better question:** is the laptop even capable of hooking up to a monitor, or are other aspects broken (e.g. the graphics card itself)? How would I go about examining this?

Comment: Many computers will move the screen to the external monitor automatically when you close the lid.  You might give that a try.

Comment: "model number is MS2273" I don't see this as an option on the Gateway support site under the NV series. Do you have another number?

Comment: Near as I can tell, MS2273 can be either the NV54 or the NV58. Neither is written on the laptop anywhere, but, going by photos, I am guessing it's an NV58.

Comment: hi @Maaatt ! about 1 year after you post the Q .. did you finally discovere the required key at end ?

Comment: hi @URL87 , this was actually a friend's computer, and we gave up; she bought a new computer, so that's that I guess. If you're having the same issue, sorry I can't help you!

Answer (score 2):

The toggle display key could be the F6 key, depending on the model you have.

> Press and hold the FN key and then tap
>   the Display Toggle key to select
>   between viewing the display only on
>   the LCD panel, viewing the display
>   only on the external display, and
>   viewing the display on both the LCD
>   panel and the external display. The
>   Display Toggle key will be either the
>   F4 or the F6 key

The key should look similar to this one  [image]

Pause for a few seconds between each key tap to give your monitor time to respond to having a signal present

Comment: That is the icon on the f4 key (f6 is bluetooth), so I'm thinking probably f4, haha! I tried again with longer pauses (ten seconds), but no luck. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to boot on the external screen when keep the lit closed during the boot.
Turn the laptop off, connect the external monitor, turn the device on again and (if the power switch is under the lit) close the lit completely immediately after turning on.

Comment: Thanks for replying! This didn't work with or without also plugging in an external keyboard and mouse.